# Automatically add more pages on wordpress multisite install

Tags: wordpress

I want to make 5 pages with a navigation on wordpress multisite.

That means when a new user registers for a new site, he/she will get a new site with 5 default pages with a navigation menu. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it at last. :)
It is in

> wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php

function name

> wp_install_defaults();

overwrite this function to generate custom posts and pages on wp install.